# Procedure to connect a composer to a personalized fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm having some challenges to actually understand the procedure to connect composer to fabric(not the samples).

My objective here is to configure a fabric network and then connect this configurated network with a composer.bna.

1. After making all the changes I want to in the network, I need to run the network with the docker composer commands correct ? just like the byfn.sh script?
2. After that I should generate a PeerAdmin card right? so i believe I should use the connection.json file and the composer-cli command or there is another way to do it ?
3. And then I can start the procedure via composer?

I'm just little confused because with fabric tools you have all those startFabric.sh and creatPeerAdmin.sh but some of them are different from de fabric-samples and well....I'm a real beginner on the subject but I just need more understanding on the procedure between a configurated network and composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you've tested your personalized Fabric environment is up and running (you mention BYFN 2-Org [Fabric] blockchain network, which is a sample network provided by Hyperledger Fabric: this performs some chaincode tests, like: `invokes` and `queries` eg  query the ledger after updating an asset: ie to ensure the scripted BYFN sample Fabric network is up and running OK). Hyperledger Composer, being a development framework and toolset (not a blockchain per se) is largely for writing smart contracts (ie business networks - and of course for writing client-side apps too)  - and it 'consumes' that Fabric infrastructure and deploys smart contracts to it, in the form of chaincode that runs as native NodeJS chaincode.

Now to Composer: If you look at the 'Multi-Org' tutorial (how to interact with a business network / smart contract, between two Orgs, and participants from those orgs), it tells you what was needed to configure Composer to be able to interact with the blockchain network, which has TLS enabled etc etc. It includes defining Connection profiles (eg what are the nodes of the network, what ports, what config parameters, what's the defined Fabric endorsement policy for the business network etc etc), business network cards (cards provide the blockchain identities the ability to transact in that business network and know 'who' performed it), what Access Control rules, what Queries to run, What transaction logic and units of work to execute, to update the blockchain ledger. Composer is one way of developing your smart contracts,  is model-driven and also aimed at taking away many of the transformatory, type-handling, validation aspects you would otherwise have to do. Your aim is to check your custom Fabric network is all running correctly (as mentioned earlier), then come to Composer, to configure the - Composer - elements, all of which are described in the Composer docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer

in answer to your questions

1. You would need to ensure your docker-compose (not 'composer') YAML files reflect the custom Fabric network you want to spin up.
2. yes, you need someone with peer admin authority/capability in Fabric, to install / and someone with minimally channel admin authority/capability to start the business network on the channel (as you'll see in the multi-org tutorial, both these are done by a Composer business network card that happens to be called PeerAdmin)
3. correct

The tools you mention in your last paragraph, are Composer tools - the aim of those scripts is to allow a Composer developer to spin up a local, Development Fabric to test against. You won't find them in 'fabric-samples' because they are provided by Composer (composer-tools) as described here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html .

Comment: Thank you, Paul, for your attention and for the help!